# Why does the boiling water in the pot get sucked up by the jar?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, temperature, gas, evaporation

In order for the jars to be sterilized for pickling tomatoes, they need to be boiled. But when one of the inverted jars was standing on the rack in the pot, it started sucking in the water that was boiling there (and sucked out almost all the water). The jars were turned over so that their open side was completely submerged in the water (so that approximately the entire surface of the neck of the jar was in contact with the grid).

An approximate drawing of what is happening from the side:
[image]

I took the jar out, emptied the water out of it, and put it back, but after a while it filled up again. The plastic grate on which the jars stood was uneven, and had holes in it.  Why does this happen? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

first water vapor enters the jar and drives the air out, then it condenses, and you have kind of a vacuum in the jar, the water outside is pressed in.
if the jar are deep enough in water this will not happen so easy, since the vapor pressure is not enough to drive the air out.